# " I want to customise my dashboard page in ActiveAdmin, But I am getting this error "Uninitialised constant Dashboards"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

This is my dashboard ruby file . I want to know what is causing the error ""Uninitialised constant Dashboards" which is in line 1st.I am using ruby on rails 4 on windows.

```
ActiveAdmin ::Dashboards.build do
    section "Recent Posts" do
        table_for Post.order("id.desc").limit(15) do
            column :id
            colunm :"Post Title",:title do |post|
            link_to post.title,(:admin.post)
            end
            column :category,:sortable => :category
            column :created_at
        end
        strong (link_to "Show all Posts")
    end
    end
```

Comment: Remove space and it should be ActiveAdmin::Dashboards

Answer (score 0):

remove the blank space in class name  -->`ActiveAdmin ::Dashboards` to `ActiveAdmin::Dashboards`